# Generar impresión en proyecto en Impresora de etiquetas Zebra GX470T

Tags: php

Buena un saludo recurro a ayuda estoy desarrollando un sistema de verificación de entrada y salida cuando se marca un check in debo imprimir una especia de etiqueta en una impresora zebra con los datos del visitante para que puedan llevar una especie de gafet, el problema es que mi cliente no puede prestarme la impresora por lo que recurro a la experiencia de alguien mas utilizando estas impresoras para saber que libreria de php puedo utilizar para lograr la comunicación entre esta impresora el sistema se utilizara de manera local estaba utilizando mike42 pero no se si sea la opción correcta ya que tendré que llegar a hacer la instalación un poco a ciegas un saludo.

Comment: ¿La impresora va a estar conectada a un servidor o a un cliente? ¿Impresora local o de red? ¿Cuál sistema operativo? ¿La  aplicación se ejecuta por navegador o por línea de comandos?.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: La impresora esta en un cliente local en windows 10 la aplicación se ejecuta por navegador utilizando los servicios locales levantados en xammp lo que necesito es obtener comunicación entre la impresora Zebra ya que no tengo manera de probar la conexión hasta el dia de instalación debido a que mi cliente no puede sacarla de la empresa mi pregunta es como establecer esa comunicacion, ya que no tengo experiencia conectando con estas impresoras de etiquetas.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí en este enlace hacen un ejemplo practico con la impresora que tu estas usando, ademas, implementado en laravel

https://parzibyte.me/blog/2020/03/04/laravel-imprimir-ticket-impresora-termica/

Tienes que instalar la libreria

```
composer require mike42/escpos-php
```

Importas la librería

```
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
```

Y aqui muestra el ejemplo de como aplicarlo

```
<?php
$nombreImpresora = "POS-58";
$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector($nombreImpresora);
$impresora = new Printer($connector);
$impresora->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_CENTER);
$impresora->setTextSize(2, 2);
$impresora->text("Imprimiendo\n");
$impresora->text("ticket\n");
$impresora->text("desde\n");
$impresora->text("Laravel\n");
$impresora->setTextSize(1, 1);
$impresora->text("https://parzibyte.me");
$impresora->feed(5);
$impresora->close();
```

debido a que no tienes la impresora en fisico, te recomiendo hacer pruebas generando  pdf, ya luego que la tengas le das los ajustes finales

Comment: Estuve testeando justamente con la libreria mike42 y logre imprimir en mi impresora personal pero he visto que estas impresoras Zebra de etiquetas son diferentes por lo que me decidi a levantar esta duda, ya que no quiero llegar a instalar y que por compatibilidad no me ande.